# Find $b$, such that the average value of a function, on a given interval is $3$.

Tags: calculus

Find the numbers $b$ such that the average value of $f(x)=2+6x-3x^2$ on the interval $[0, b]$ is $3$.

I have no clue how to proceed in this question

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Average value of a continuous function $y=f(x)$ in the interval $(A,B)$ is given by $$y_{\text{avg.}}=\frac{\displaystyle \int_A^B f(x) \mathrm dx}{B-A}$$

In your case $f(x)=2+6x-3x^2$ and $A=0 ; B=b$.